# Non- negative and float solutions needed

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a simple algebra problem, the solutions can be real, and complex.

I am looking there only the positive and real solutions, in this case I have written the following example:

Mostly I have tried to ask python for every member in the answer list the "type(ans) is float and after ask if its positive".

```
    res = sp.solve(self.dflux * (self.u - u_0) - (self.flux - flux_0), self.u)

        for it in res:
            print(it)
            if(type(it) is float):
                print('here')

    print(type(res),res)
```

for example in the following case

```
<class 'list'> [-0.707106781186548, 0.0, 0.707106781186548]
```

I see no "here" at all.

the same happens for the next case

```
<class 'list'> [0.0, 0.793216505472184, -0.398143686499772 - 0.949955974569196*I, -0.398143686499772 + 0.949955974569196*I, 0.603391747263908 - 2.16302515309992*I, 0.603391747263908 + 2.16302515309992*I]
```

I was expecting to see here 3 times for the first example, and two times for the second one, but nothing.

New part:

I have slightly changed the script for the following version:

```
    for it in res:
        print(it)
        print(isinstance(it,float),type(it))
        if(isinstance(it,float) == True):
            print('here')
```

The output i see for the first case, is the next:

```
-0.707106781186548
 False <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>

 0.0
 False <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>

 0.707106781186548
 False <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>

 <class 'list'> [-0.707106781186548, 0.0, 0.707106781186548]
```

Really strange for me this behavior. In one hand pythons says is not a float but in the other hand it says it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a quirk of SymPy, where a sumpy Float != a python float. (Note the capitalization)

Observe:

```
import sympy

x=float(16)
x
16.0

isinstance(x,float)
True

y=sympy.Float(x)
y
16.0000000000000

type(y)
sympy.core.numbers.Float

isinstance(y,float)
False

isinstance(y,sympy.Float)
True
```

So I would say the solution to the type-checking is in the last line, `sympy.Float`

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really useful to learn that each environment (sympy, numpy, python,math,etc) might have different "type names"....

Comment: In this case let me ask you the next issue:

    y = sympy.Float(1)

is correct to assume that:

y > 0

shall the terminal return true???

Comment: The best thing to do if you aren't sure on something like this is to test it in the console. For example, you can run `sympy.Float(1)==float(1)` or `sympy.Float(1)>=0` and see what is returned (in this case both return `True`). In this case, it looks like (unsurprisingly) sympy has implemented full support for `__eq__, __gt__`, etc operators in the code, it's just the object type that is different.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is a function for that:

```
isinstance(0.56, float)



>> true
```

> Edit

there is no need to do `if(expresion == True)`, you just can do `if(expresion)`

In your case, your float is not python float, is sympy float, so you just have to do:

```
import sympy

isinstance(sympy.Float(0.56),sympy.Float)
for it in res:
    if(isinstance(it,sympy.Floa)):
        print('here')
```

Comment: I have changed the script, regarding your comment, look the output I get...

Comment: @AndresValdez I edited the answer based on your edits